# Fatal: Module ndiswrapper not found

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, ndiswrappers

Getting the following error message:

> Fatal: Module ndiswrapper not found

Problem is I did install the `ndiswrapper` module. I even uninstalled and re-installed it. Still nothing. Any reason?

On Linux Mint 14

My network controller is a Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE and something about (rev 01)

It is using module rtl8192ce. Not sure if it should be using _common or not.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ndiswrappers are you using, the 32-bit or 64-bit? According to this forum thread, titled: [Error ndiswrapper not found](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=194&t=101574), the 64-bit version of `ndiswrapper` is problematic.

Digging deeper in that thread I found this link titled: [12.04 and ndiswrapper modprode "FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11970543). The solution to the problem in that thread is to install the following packages:

- ndiswrapper-source
- ndiswrapper-dkms
- ndiswrapper-common
- (And of course, install ndiswrapper-utils-1.9)

#### References

- [WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper - ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper)

Comment: I installed those. However none of those come up in my list of kernel modules.

Comment: Additional things to try in this thread: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ndiswrapper/+bug/1023645

Comment: @Griffin - this video might be helpful, I think you need to downgrade to 1.58rc1, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjF5kNSunTk

Comment: That's a great idea..... if I had an internet connection that didn't cut out. I can no longer plug it in so there is a problem.

Comment: @Griffin - if you have internet access on another computer you can use a usb thumbdrive to sneaker net the files over.

Comment: Those machines aren't linux and I don't know any formats that play nice on both sides

Comment: @Griffin - Any thumbdrive that can be read by windows can be read by linux. FAT32 or NTFS are fine under both.

Comment: I've found it doesn't like NTFS

Comment: @Griffin - What about FAT32?

Comment: I'll try it in the morning